# Simple query to search a term in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I build a little search input in my site, its kind of working, the problem is that it show all the items as results, so it isn't really searching, it just throw all the table..

my query look like this

```
// Get page data
$query1 = "SELECT id,tienda,descripcion,local,img FROM $tableName WHERE tienda LIKE '%$term%' ";
$result = mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
```

if i remove the % symbol of $term , then i got "no results" , so what am i missing.

What i need is to search for exact and partial coincidences, for example, "Go" should throw "google" as result..

thanks,

Comment: See if the variable `$term` has any value

Comment: **mysql_*** functions are deprecated and will be removed sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** Check if the variable `$term` is returning a value. ex: `if($term)`

**2nd:**   The use of wild card `%` in both sides of the `$term` is like a `SELECT *` statement without `WHERE` conditions if the variable `$term` is EMPTY or NULL. (see [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)).

---

* Note that the mysql extension [is now **deprecated** and will be removed sometime in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). That's because it is ancient, full of bad practices and lacks some modern features. Don't use it to write new code. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Your query is prone to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Ok thanks i actually check i guess there is an error on that part, i did not paste that parte of code